# ¿Por qué no se pasan los parametros a este modal de Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, django

¿Qué pasa que no me pasan los parámetros al modal? Aquí esta el código que usé. Muchas gracias al que me pueda ayudar. El modal funciona perfectamente; lo que no me recibe son los parámetros a mostrar en éste.

```
<td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="btmodal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id={{valessw.id}} data-numero={{valessw.codigo}} data-fecha={{valessw.fecha}}><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></td>

  <script>
   $(document).on("click", "#btmodal", function () {
     var idc=$(this).data(id);
     var numeroc=$(this).data(numero);
     var fechac=$(this).data(fecha);

     $("#plot1").val(numeroc);
     $("#plot2").val(fechac);
   })

  </script>
    



   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         Decea eliminar el vale numero <label id="plot1"></label> con fecha <label id="plot2"></label>  
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: En el click del elemento que supuestamente lanza el modal, recoges en variables valores, pero en el cuerpo del modal no veo el uso de esas variables. Con val() no le puedes establecer el texto, usa text() o HTML()